# Why does <code> tagged text result in line break on mobile but not on desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a website section in Javascript that displays a series of projects in a table, whose code essentially looks like this:

```
export const items = [
  {
    client: "Client 1",
    dates: "March 2023",
    description: "Placeholder of random text",
    tags: ["in progress"],
    tech: ["JS", "CSS"]
  }, {
    client: "Client 2",
    dates: "March 2023",
    description: "Placeholder of random text using <code>BufferedReader</code> to print.",
    tags: ["completed"],
    tech: ["JS", "HTML", "CSS"]
  },]
```

I'm trying to use the code tag around the text BufferedReader to display it as a code block (in a different font and colour). When the website is viewed on desktop, the text BufferedReader stays in line with the rest of the paragraph. However, when viewed on mobile, the text results in a line break.

I have also tried to add the following code to the CSS file, but to no effect.

```
code{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to add `display: inline;` to the CSS rule.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)